# @IBInspectable not working either with making class as @IBDesignable

Tags: swift2

i am trying to make my variable initialization custom and put in utilities of the story board but it is not coming in the utilities section my UIView class implementation can appear on my storyboard using @IBDesignable i have no reputation to put images

Comment: with out any code. no idea...